# POSIX and Bash, sh shorthand, for compound if statement

Tags: bash, shell, posix, dash

I prefer to do my `sh` commands in shorthand, And I prefer to be in POSIX.  Truthfully, if the script can run on Dash, that is good enough.  Which means using the test command `[`, not the extended `[[`.

I have an example from an autostart script, which I'm not sure about.

```
if which dbus-launch >/dev/null && test -z "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"; then
   eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session`
fi
```

So my guess is that if `dbus-launch` and `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` is empty, then do the `eval`.
How do I write this in shorthand?   I appreciate any help on this subject.

Comment: To confirm, what is the command flow that you're actually wanting? I don't fully understand from your question.

Comment: I want the same command flow as before, just written in dash compatible shorthand. So instead of if ... then ... fi, I much prefer [ ... ] && ...

for example "test -z "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" is comparable to [ -z "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" ].  I just don't know how to do a long nested example like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The snippet you posted is POSIX-legal and should run fine on `dash` as is.  I don't understand the point of expunging `if`s and replacing them with one-liners, as it doesn't actually accomplish much besides occasionally making code harder to read.  Nevertheless, in this case, since it's just a single line, you can simply delete the `if`, `; then`, and `fi` and replace the `; then` with a `&&`, i.e.

```
which dbus-launch >/dev/null && test -z "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" && 
eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session`
```

should be functionally equivalent to the snippet in the question.  Also, if this is what you mean by "shorthand", I don't think it's a universal or standard term and it doesn't save too many characters of typing.  *Converting an `if` compound command to a list* would be a more accurate description.

Comment: truthfully, i find the && and || easiest to read, its only really a problem for people who don't write shell.  

so I also could write it like this,
`command -v dbus-launch > /dev/null && [ -z "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" ] && eval \`dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session\``

but is the eval really necessary? How is it different from 
`command -v dbus-launch > /dev/null && [ -z "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" ] && dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session`

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here.  While `&&` and `||` with `{ }`can replace certain `if` constructs with care and some awkwardness in syntax, this has very little to do with `eval`.  The `dbus-launch --sh-syntax` will print environment variable assignments to its standard output, e.g. to set `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`, and the `eval` is what actually runs those assignments in the current shell.  Dropping the `eval` will mean those assignments never run, which means programs you run won't know where to find the dbus session bus, which means things will probably break.

Comment: O got it, but whats the difference between backticks and eval?
like this 

`command -v dbus-launch > /dev/null && [ -z "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" ] && \`dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session\``

Comment: Command substitution happens after variable assignments.  Without eval you'll get a message like `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=whatever_its_contents_should_be: no such command`. You need `eval` to interpret the command substitution output the way the shell would, or else the shell will just attempt to execute the output directly.

Comment: @TechZilla Using gratuitous “shorthand” is against my personal style guidelines, and I don't think I qualify as “people who don't write shell”. The only reason to use `&&` instead of `if` is if you want the return status of the whole command to be nonzero if `dbus` is not available or `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` is empty.

Comment: @Gilles, I assume the reason the original author used a &&, was for the desired return status.  In addition, I really would have been best off avoiding my generalization about readability.  As any generalization has outliers, regardless if it is usually correct or not. It's a lose/lose.  If you are more correct, someone tells you they are the outlier.  If your less correct, someone tells you that as well.  You could say avoiding `if` is in my personal style guidelines.  What I meant about readability... If you know bash, you can understand it.  Personally I find it easier to understand.

Comment: My general rule is to use whatever makes more sense: `if`s are control structures for *statements* and "*actions*", while `&&` and `||` operators operate on boolean *values* and logical *conditions*.  In this case, I find the original snippet to be in the most sensible style as it is written in the form of 2 conditions in an `if` test guarding against the execution of an *action*, the `dbus-launch` itself, and its exit status doesn't really matter.